# How do I use sum and count functions together on different columns in my data frame function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data frame is the following:

```
Advertiser      Product             Price
Company1        A                   10
Company1        A                   10
Company1        B                   8
Company2        C                   5
Company3        D                   3
```

My current function is:

```
top_5_products = df.groupby(['Advertiser'])['Product'].value_counts(ascending = False).head(5)
```

It outputs the following:

```
Advertiser      Product
Company 1       A   2
                B   1
Company 2       C   1
Company 3       D   1
```

What is the best way to modify my function to give me the sum of the price as well? Example:

```
Advertiser      Product     Total Price
Company 1       A   2       20
                B   1       8
Company 2       C   1       5
Company 3       D   1       3
```

I have looked at the .agg method but I'm lacking examples that use different columns. (I'm also not sure if that's the best way to go about it) Thanks!

Edit***

```
df.groupby(['Advertiser', 'Product']).agg({'Product': 'count', 'Price': 'sum'}).head(5)
```

doesn't work as it is no longer sorted...

Comment: So, you want all these in one line?

Comment: No, like my output example. As a data frame object.

Comment: I mean, if you want to have on the same line of code, the groupby, the sum etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone commented with the answer, but it disappeared shortly after. Thankfully I saw it and it works. Thank you!

The following code works:

```
df.groupby(['Advertiser','Product']).agg({'Product': 'count', 'Price': 'sum'}).head(5)
```

EDIT*** This does not work as it no longer sorts.

Comment: Well, he answered it again, so you can remove your answer and accept his as correct.

Answer (score 2):

groupby with [agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html)

```
df.groupby(['Advertiser', 'Product']).agg({'Product': 'count', 'Price': 'sum'})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it doesn't sort now though. How would I sort by the count?

Comment: @joshgallantt you can add `.sort_values(by='Product')` to the end